# If B span $V$ and |B|=n so B is linear independent

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let there be V a vector space, $dim(V)=n$.
B spans V, |B|=n, prove that B is linear independent

Let there be $B \subseteq S $ where S span $V$ too, Because |B|=n then |S|>n and B is a basis, therefore it is also linear independent

Comment: One way to do this would be to assume that B is instead linearly dependent, in which case at least one vector in B can be written as a linear combination of the remaining vectors.  Then these remaining n-1 vectors would still span V, and this is impossible since an n-dim. vector space cannot have a spanning set of n-1 vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. If $B \subseteq S$, then $|S| > n$ isn't necessarily true, as $|S|$ could be equal to $n$.
2. Could you elaborate on the statement: "Because $|B| = n$, then $|S|>n$ [sic] and $B$ is a basis." Is there some theorem you are drawing on to come to this conclusion?